How to Integrate a React Component from One React App into Another React App Using CDN
I'm trying to display a component from one React application within another React app using a CDN. Although the component works perfectly in its original application, I encountered an error related to the Use State hook when importing it via the CDN. This error is preventing the component from functioning correctly. How can I resolve this issue?
What I Tried and What I Expected:
I am rendering components from App 1 into App 2 by building App 1 and serving it through localhost on port 8000.
Desired Behavior:
The component should integrate seamlessly and function correctly within the host React app without any issues related to Use State.
Problem:
When importing the component via CDN, I encounter an error related to the use state, which does not occur when the component is used within its original application. How can I resolve this issue?
Code Snippets and Configurations:
App 1/Button.jsx
import React from 'react';

import { useState } from "react";

export default function Button() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  return (
    <>
      <p>Value is {count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </>
  );
}

App 2/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
    <!-- Include React and ReactDOM before your component script -->
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/dist/my-component.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>

App 2/App.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [MyComponent, setMyComponent] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.MyComponent) {
      console.log('window MyComponent is here', window.MyComponent);
      setMyComponent(() => window.MyComponent.Button);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {MyComponent ? <MyComponent /> : <p>Loading...</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

App 1/Webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/components/Button.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'my-component.bundle.js',
    library: 'MyComponent',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
  externals: {
    react: 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  mode: 'production',
};

Error Faced:
Error Facing when rendering 

use code snippets in your question instead of images whenever possible. Please edit your question and replace the images.

I didn't downvote, but please read these links: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode and https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/
